# Unknown logical error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm assuming it's a logical error because it doesn't return any compiler or run-time errors.

my functions:

```
function closetest() {
   tooclose=false;
   for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(entry[0]-entry[i])<100) {
        tooclose=true;
     }
   }
}

function xassignment() {
  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    entry[i+1]=entry[i];
  }
  do {
      entry[0] = int(Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - 30));
      closetest();
  } while (tooclose == false);
}
```

Here is where the function is called

```
mcMain.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);
function moveChar(event:Event):void {
if (gameOver == false) {
    if (enemyTime < enemyLimit) {
        enemyTime++;
    } else {
        var newEnemy = new Enemy();
        xassignment();
        newEnemy.y=-1*newEnemy.height;
        newEnemy.x=entry[0];
        addChild(newEnemy);
        enemyTime=0;
    }
}
}
```

I'm making a game that involves objects being dropped from a randomly generated x coordinate, I made these functions to make sure that objects aren't being dropped too close to each other but it doesn't appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't described what effect you are observing, but I noticed this:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(entry[0]-entry[i])<100) {
        tooclose=true;
    }
}
```

This will result in `tooclose` always being true, because your loop begins at 0, therefore you compare `entry[0]` with itself.  Try starting the loop at 1 instead.

Comment: I changed that but it didn't solve it.

The effect I'm observing is as if tooclose is always false and some objects will be right on top of each other

Comment: Then you should be more specific about what the actual problem is, and show how these functions are used.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared or changed `tooclose` within `xassignment`. You should instead return a Boolean from `closetest()` which will be queried. Another logical error is, you are advancing previous values by 1 in your array, while incrementing the index. So you have i=0, entry[1]=entry[0]. Then `i` is incremented, entry[2]=entry[1] - bam, entry[2] too starts being requal to entry[0]! And so on, so the entire array of entries now equals to what was rolled on the previous attempt, instead of storing 10 previous values. Fixed that too.

```
function closetest():Boolean {
    for (var i:int=1; i<10; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(entry[0]-entry[i])<100) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
function xassignment() {
    for (i=10; i>0; i--) entry[i]=entry[i-1];
    do {
        entry[0] = int(Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - 30));
    } while(closetest());
}
```

Note though, if your `closetest` implementation will receive a `[X,100,300,500,700]` array the loop will be endless, as there's no X position that will satisfy your range of 100 for absolute difference. So, fix it with the following:

```
function xassignment() {
    for (i=10; i>0; i--) entry[i]=entry[i-1];
    var loops:int=10;
    do {
        entry[0] = int(Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - 30));
        loops--;
    } while((loops>0)&&closetest());
}
```

This will force an exit from that loop if we tried 10 randoms and none satisfied - the last attempt is returned.